# Salesforce: Use one of these records? on API response

Tags: php, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I was trying to set up a sync between our application and Salesforce to sync the data bidirectionally. I am using API to do so and the API is returning with the response below.

```
HTTP CODE: 400
Response :  [{"message":"Use one of these records?","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION","fields":[]}]
```

I Googled and figured that it might be due to duplicate or matching rules set up in SF. Is this is the case and if it's possible to override this setting somehow? Also, can someone suggest how can we know what rule or value caused the duplicate issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of Duplicate Rules in Salesforce. Your API client can configure this behavior only if

1. You are using the Salesforce SOAP API (not the REST API).
2. The Duplicate Rule is configured to Alert, rather than to Block.

If both are true, you can configure a [`DuplicateRuleHeader`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_duplicateruleheader.htm#!) on your SOAP requests to bypass this duplicate rule.

Otherwise, you'll need to adjust your Duplicate Rule, which will be associated with the sObject for which this request failed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's too late for your feature, but hopefully someone else comes across this.

I'd work with your Salesforce Admin to see if you can bypass your duplication rules setup on your SObject.

Our organization did something similar and we went forward with setting conditionals that if the user profile matched our integration user, we'd ignore the duplicate rules setup.

You can find these duplicate rules by Home -> Setup -> Data -> Duplicate Management -> Duplicate Rules.